# Air Native Extension BroadcastReceiver not fired

Tags: android, alarmmanager, ane

I'm trying to make an ANE that can dispatch an event to AIR on a service call.
I have no errors when creating the service, but my broadcast doesn't seem to be called.
Here is my AlarmCreation (I have remove unnecessary code)

```
 public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {

        FREObject pData = args[0];

        myUserData = new AlarmInterfaceUserData();
        myUserData.setContext(context);

        myUserData.setsHeure(pData.getProperty("heures").getAsString());
        myUserData.setsDate(pData.getProperty("jours").getAsString());
        myUserData.setbRepeat(pData.getProperty("repeat").getAsBool());


        String[] sHeures = myUserData.getsHeure().split(":");
        String[] sDates = myUserData.getsDate().split("-");
        Boolean bRepeat = myUserData.isbRepeat();

        String sTemp1 = null;

        Context myAppContext = context.getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.atnetplanet.alarmInterface.BroadcastReceiver");
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        myIntent.putExtra("repeatWhenTime", false);

        for(String sDay : sDates){
            int iDay;
            if(sDay == "SUNDAY") iDay = 1;
            else if(sDay == "MONDAY") iDay = 2;
            else if(sDay == "TUESDAY") iDay = 3;
            else if(sDay == "WEDNESDAY") iDay = 4;
            else if(sDay == "THURSDAY") iDay = 5;
            else if(sDay == "FRIDAY") iDay = 6;
            else iDay = 7;

            String sTemp2 = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
            sTemp2 = sTemp2.substring(sTemp2.length()-10, sTemp2.length());

            Integer nCodeAlarm = 123456;
            myIntent.putExtra("id", nCodeAlarm);

            PendingIntent myAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(myAppContext, nCodeAlarm, myIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager myAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, iDay);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(sHeures[0]));
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(sHeures[1]));
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if(bRepeat == true){
                myAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, myAlarmIntent);
            } else{
                myAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), myAlarmIntent);
            }


            if(sTemp1 == null)
                sTemp1 = Integer.toString(nCodeAlarm);
            else
                sTemp1 = sTemp1+"/"+Integer.toString(nCodeAlarm);   
        }

        FREObject mesAlarm = null;
        try {
            mesAlarm = FREObject.newObject(sTemp1);
        } catch (FREWrongThreadException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mesAlarm;

    }
```

My Broadcast receiver is, for now really simple

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "On recupere une alarme", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        myUserData = AlarmInterfaceUserData.getInstance();
        myUserData.getContext().dispatchStatusEventAsync("DATA_CHANGED", "Faut se reveiller");

    }
```

and at last my manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" package="com.atnetplanet">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.atnetplanet.alarminterface.AlarmInterfaceCreateAlarmFunction"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_ALARM"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.atnetplanet.alarminterface.AlarmInterfaceDispatchAlarm"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <receiver 
            android:name="com.atnetplanet.alarminterface.AlarmInterfaceBroadcastReceiver" 
            android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.atnetplanet.alarminterface.AlarmInterfaceDispatchAlarm" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If someone could give me some intels I'll be really helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With your manifest you need to make sure that the all the additions are inside your AIR application descriptor. The actual AndroidManifest.xml file that is created with your library is never used by an AIR application.

Comment: Hello,thank you for your answer. To solve my problem I created my Intent differently  In fact the AndroidManifest is used by my Air Application (I have another problem with it here for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700674/air-app-adding-activity-to-manifest-changes-the-app-design ).

Comment: I created my Intent this way :  Context myAppContext = context.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
Intent myIntent = new Intent(myAppContext, AlarmInterfaceBroadcastReceiver.class);

Comment: Yeah okay, I think I see your other problem.  In your myIntent you were launching the "com.atnetplanet.alarmInterface.BroadcastReceiver" Action but didn't have that specified in your manifest. Changing it to the class definition should have fixed that.